# Convert normal space/whitespace to non-breaking space?

Tags: unicode, encoding, character-encoding, go, unicode-string

This is a simple question, but I still can't figure out how to do it.

Say I have this string:

```
x := "this string"
```

The whitespace between 'this' and 'string' defaults to the *regular* unicode whitespace character `32/U+0020`. How would I convert it into the *non-breaking* unicode whitespace character `U+00A0` in Go?

Comment: Sudden downvotes? I disagree; I think this is a useful question, especially since I spent a couple hours on Google trying to figure it out without success.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think a basic way to do it is by creating a simple function:

http://play.golang.org/p/YT8Cf917il

```
package main

import "fmt"

func ReplaceSpace(s string) string {
    var result []rune
    const badSpace = '\u0020'
    for _, r := range s {
        if r == badSpace {
            result = append(result, '\u00A0')
            continue
        }
        result = append(result, r)
    }
    return string(result)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(ReplaceSpace("this string"))
}
```

If you need more advanced manipulations you could create something with

```
"golang.org/x/text/transform"
"golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm"
```

Read http://blog.golang.org/normalization for more information on how to use it

Comment: Didn't know about the special string([]rune) encoding/conversion! That's neat.

Comment: Or for any white space `strings.Map` which is effectively what you've re-implemented here.

Answer (score 4):

Use the documentation to identify the standard `strings` package as a likely candidate, and then search it (or read through it all, you should know what's available in the standard library/packages of any language you use) to find [`strings.Map`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Map).

Then the obvious short simple solution to convert *any* white space would be:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "unicode"
)

func main() {
    const nbsp = '\u00A0'
    result := strings.Map(func(r rune) rune {
        if unicode.IsSpace(r) {
            return nbsp
        }
        return r
    }, "this string")

    fmt.Printf("%s → %[1]q\n", result)
}
```

[<kbd>Playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/1kJD21kyin)

As previously mentioned, if you really only want to replace `" "` then perhaps `strings.Replace`.